# Git - Unmerge after other commits have been made

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

The image illustrates my merge history, including a merge that I had done prior to several more recent commits. Can I undo this merge, while keeping the commits that I have done after? I merged with develop when I should have merged with master.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This kind of thing is covered [here](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html).

You will likely need to `revert` and `merge` depending on your situation.

Comment: I saw this reference, but I found it to be a bit confusing. I couldnt figure out wich commands to use.

Comment: @RafaelReis use `git revert -m 1 [sha]`. You can find the sha using `git log`

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you could first run `git log` to get a list of commits. Then, you would run `git checkout` to a different branch (if you don't have one, use `git branch <branch name>` to create. Finally, run `git reset --hard <commit ID for your commit of interest>`. This will permanently undo your merge commit since the point you choose.

Comment: I can not see this working. I need to keep the commits ive done after the merge. I just dont want the files added in the merge. Your solutions seams to be going back before the merge, so i would lose the commits.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
git revert -m 1 <sha1>
```

where `<sha1>` is the merge commit you want to get rid of.

Described here:
https://mijingo.com/blog/reverting-a-git-merge

Comment: Is this going to preserve the commits ive made after?

Comment: A revert should never do anything other than removing the CONTENT of the reverted commit, so yes. But this also means it will actually not remove the merge either, only revert it.